# Can C++ disambiguate the type of an exception object?

Tags: c++, exception

With empty exception objects such as,

```
class E1
{
};

class E2
{
};
```

Can C++('s compiler or the resulting executable) safely disambiguate between such exception objects in a catch statement? If so, does it mean that a type code for each exception object should be stored and tracked internally?

Comment: Your objects don't inherit from `std::exception` so I don't really see what you're trying to do. If you want to know the type of an object at runtime you need to enable reflection or give them virtual functions you can call. Since your two classes are unrelated, if you catch `E1` it will only catch `E1` and same for `E2`.

Comment: That's strange. I've been throwing exceptions for ten years, that have not been derived from std::exception, just fine. How did I manage to do it?

Comment: Disambiguation would require that there be some ambiguity to start with. There isn't. The fact that they're both empty doesn't change the fact that E1 and E2 are separate and distinct classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the C++ runtime will choose the appropriate catch block based on the type of the exception thrown. You can use multiple catch blocks to handle different types of exceptions

```
try 
{
    throw E2();
}
catch (E1)
{
    std::cout << "Caught E1";
}
catch (E2)
{
    std::cout << "Caught E2";
}

// Output: "Caught E2"
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. E1 and E2 are distinct and separate classes. What they contain, is immaterial.